# Update marker's popUp content without rewriting all HTML leaflet

Tags: jquery, html, popup, leaflet, marker

I would like to know if there's a way to change the content of a marker's popUp without having to rewrite all the html that is already there, I mean, I would like to toggle a class of one of the element inside of the popUp, it appears that the class exist in the DOM, and it toggles right, but after I close the popUp of the markers, returns to it's previous state, as If toggle hasn't applied, I believe is because I need to change the initial HTML of the popUp, I would like to do this without having to rewrite all the html I already built, and since is a pretty heavy html, is complicated to rewrite everything, I tried using update() method, but is not working, hope somebody can help me,

```
var objeto = Layerpints._layers;
  for(r in objeto){
    var html = Layerpints._layers[r]._popup._content;
    var html_parse = $.parseHTML(html);
    var up_tick    = $(html_parse).find('.up_tick');
  }
  $(up_tick).each(function(e){
      var id_pint_name = $(this).attr('name');
      if(id == id_pint_name){
        if($(this).hasClass('text-info')){
          console.log("remove class");
          $(this).removeClass('text-info');
          Layerpints._layers[r]._popup.update();
        }else{
          console.log("add Class");
          $(this).addClass('text-info');
          Layerpints._layers[r]._popup.update();
        }
      }else{
        console.log("do nothing");
      }
  });
```

this is the code I'm trying to use hope someone could help, thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to fixed it by changing the update() method to setContent() method like this

```
var objeto = Layerpints._layers;
  for(r in objeto){
    var html = Layerpints._layers[r]._popup._content;
    var html_parse = $.parseHTML(html);
    var up_tick    = $(html_parse).find('.up_tick');
  }
  $(up_tick).each(function(e){
    var id_pint_name = $(this).attr('name');
      if(id == id_pint_name){
        if($(this).hasClass('text-info')){
          $(this).removeClass('text-info');
          Layerpints._layers[r]._popup.setContent();
        }else{
          $(this).addClass('text-info');
          Layerpints._layers[r]._popup.setContent();
        }
      }else{
        console.log("do nothing");
      }
  });
```

the truth is I don't know why this is working since I believed setContent() will empty my popUp but it didn't, perhaps someone could explain further, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make good use of `L.Util.Template`:

> Simple templating facility, accepts a template string of the form 'Hello {a}, {b}' and a data object like {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}, returns evaluated string ('Hello foo, bar'). You can also specify functions instead of strings for data values — they will be evaluated passing data as an argument.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#util-template

```
L.Util.template('Hello {w}', {w: 'world'});
```